# Force the redirection to be in a specific browser

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, browser

I use this JS code to make a redirection and open a new link but when i run it it opens the link in the same browser which may be the default browser of phone but i want it to make the redirect open the link in a specific browser which is google chrome

```
window.location.href = "http://example.net"
```

How to do that ?

Comment: That is impossible in JS from within a web page. Fortunately.

Comment: is there any way to do that ?